# Send an email with several dates in body of message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a script to automatically send emails to the Manager when the auditor has not completed an audit despite 2 previous email reminders. Here is my script:

```js
//Email to Manager for incomplete Internal Audit Register Review
function sendManagerInternalAuditRegisterEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Internal Audit Register").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange(17,1).getValue(); //Cell A17

  for (var i = 3;i<=lastRow;i++){ //From row 3 to the last row

    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 12).getValue(); //Column L
    var firstName = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Column K
    var managerName = sheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue(); //Column M
    var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 14).getValue(); //Cell N1
    var date = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Column G - date added to spreadsheet
    var date2 = sheet.getRange(i, 15).getValue(); //Column O - date of first email reminder
    var date3 = sheet.getRange(i, 16).getValue(); //Column P - date of second email reminder
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy")
    var formattedDate2 = Utilities.formatDate(date2, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy")
    var formattedDate3 = Utilities.formatDate(date3, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy")
    var type = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //Column A
    var id = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); //Column B
    var title = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); //Column C
    var reason = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); //Column D
    var messageBody = message.replace("{Name}",firstName). replace("{Manager}",managerName).replace("{Type}",type).replace("{ID}",id).replace("{Title}",title).replace("{Reason}",reason).replace("{Date}",formattedDate).replace("{Date2}",formattedDate2).replace("{Date3}",formattedDate3);
    var subject = "Incomplete Internal Audit Review Task"; 
    var sendDate = sheet.getRange(i, 17).getValue(); //Column Q - date of email to Manager advising that the Auditor is still yet to complete the audit
    var sheetDate = new Date(sendDate);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate,"GMT+1300","dd MMMM yyyy")
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,"GMT+1300", "dd MMMM yyyy")
    
    
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var subject = "Reminder - Internal Audit Review Task";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);
      
    }    
  }
}
```

There are 4 dates:

- date = the date the required audit task was added to the spreadsheet.
  This date appears in the body of the email message.
- date2 = the date of the first reminder email sent to the Auditor as it had not been
  completed. There is a separate script for the first email. This date
  is in the script above to inform the Manager of the date the previous
  email had been sent to the Auditor. See the body of the email message
  template below.
- date3 = the date of the second reminder email sent to the Auditor as it had not been completed. There is a separate script for the second email. This date is in the script above to
  inform the manager of the date the previous email was sent to the auditor. See the body of the email message template below.
- sendDate = the date to send the email to the Auditor's Manager.

I keep getting the following message at date2 and date3:

```
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
```

sendManagerInternalAuditRegisterEmails

[image: Email Message Template]

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the new Date() constructor around the data recovered from the spreadsheet.  Evidently that data is a string and not a Date() object.

```
function sendManagerInternalAuditRegisterEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Internal Audit Register").activate();
  const vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  const message = ss.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange("A17").getValue();
  const todaysDate = new Date( sh.getRange(1, 14).getValue());
  vs.forEach(([type, id, title, reason, , , date, , , , firstName, email, managerName, n, date2, date3,q], i) => {
    let fDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy")
    let fDate2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date2), "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy");//try wrapping the new Date() constructor around the data from the spread because the code is seeing it  as a string.
    let fDate3 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date3), "GMT+1300", "dd MMMMM yyyy");//same as above
    let messageBody = message.replace("{Name}", firstName).replace("{Manager}", managerName).replace("{Type}", type).replace("{ID}", id).replace("{Title}", title).replace("{Reason}", reason).replace("{Date}", fDate).replace("{Date2}", fDate2).replace("{Date3}", fDate3);
    let subject = "Incomplete Internal Audit Review Task";
    let sheetDate = new Date(q);
    Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMM yyyy")
    SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, "GMT+1300", "dd MMMM yyyy")
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate) {
      subject = "Reminder - Internal Audit Review Task";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, messageBody);
    }
  })
}
```

- [new Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much